# how to integrate the dll of a reference in exe during Build?

Tags: c#

I'm new in coding.
I create an c# wpf project, I integrated 2 following references:
-System.Threading.Tasks.NET35 with NuGet package
-WPFToolkit by adding a reference from a DLL.

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6EOK.png)
My problem is when I build, Visual Studio creates multiple files :
-1 file .exe
-2 files .dll which matches the references I added.
[Build files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9YBQ.png)
How to build without generating these 2 DLLs which correspond to the references?
I just want 1 file .exe

Comment: While you *could* use [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge), I'd strongly recommend that you try to live with having DLLs separate from the EXE. That's by far the most common deployment situation. If you ever run into problems with dependencies etc, you're more likely to be able to find answers if you're deploying in a common way.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is also possible to have the DLLs as resources, and load them dynamically in `Main()`. But, yeah, best not to go down that road unless no other option.

Comment: What Mr. Skeet said. Seriously. And, look up [XCOPY deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/deploying-a-wpf-application-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for how to make it work.

Comment: I do this all the time... I have actually created a little framework to do this. It makes building self updating WPF apps easier and it allows me to do things like "swapping" a dll on the fly... at runtime easier. If you go this route you must know that certain dlls will not be happy to be loaded from memory and will require to be copied to the file system first. For example C++ dlls that require security info to run etc

Comment: I would even argue this is a quite common scenario. For example for building self contained downloadable apps. Also for apps that are run by "Updaters/Launcher" apps.  Because it is easier to for example download a single "Dependencies Container" dll and "unpack it" in memory then "hijack" the assembly resolution process to "serve" the actuall dlls from a collection of byte arrays in memory.

Comment: That being said this whole thing is a rather advanced scenario so you have to weight the cost/benefit and decide if you really need to go this way.

Comment: .Thanks for your feedback. 
It's just a personal project to get started in development so I don't have to deploy it. This is a project targeted on a server in Framework 3.5 and I cannot merge with ILMerge
Message: "An exception occurred during merging:
Platform '3.5' not recognized.
   à ILMerging.ILMerge.SetTargetPlatform(String platform, String dir)
   à ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   à ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)"

Comment: I try targetplatform v4 instead of v3.5 and it work.
Why doesn't work with v3.5?
C:\Users\wep\Downloads\ILMergeGUILatest>ILMerge Outilencaissement.exe /targetplatform:"4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" System.Threading.Tasks.NET35.dll WPFToolkit.dll /out:OutilencaissementMerged.exe

Comment: Finally, I managed to compile into 1 single file. As mentioned by @Charlieface, I put the DLLs as resources and put some code to load them on startup.
[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)